# Open Graph Read Action doesn´t show on Activity Log

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api, azure, facebook-opengraph

We did an implementation of a read action. Here what is happening:

- When we do the POST from our application, it worked well, no errors, and return the ID.
- With this ID, I can see the json data about my read action on Graph Api Explore.
- The article parameter, contains the url with OG meta tags to Article Object. If we get our url and use the Facebook Debug Tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), we can see the correct meta tags, without errors.

**Now, the problem: If I go to my activity log on Facebook account, I can´t see the read action. Is like it never was posted to Facebook.**

What is weird, is we have other action to PUBLISH. It uses the same code to build the parameters and post to Facebook, and it works great.

The api url´s we are posting:

- **Read**: https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads
- **Publish**: https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.publishes

We are requesting "**publish_actions**" permission from users.

A sample of our OG meta tags on article parameter uri:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="00000000"> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://domain.cloudapp.net/article/article-title">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Web Site Name">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.blob.core.windows.net/public/cover/rld9a28ok8smi63d33q8s1iwhve8taf2.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="James Bond: 50 Years of Movies">
<meta property="og:description" content="James Bond: 50 Years of Movies infographic from hrblock.com is all about Bond, James Bond. See the top grossing films, iconic bond accessories and more."> 
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2013-01-28">
```

A bit more of information:

- I´m in developers section of our Facebook application.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

An engineer from Facebook responded to [a ticket pertaining to built-in action types](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/452585014808810) stating:

> Sorry, but this is by design. We have deprecated these action types as they create a poor user experience. Users have complained that these actions are spammy. You can still publish them and retrieve them if you wish, but we will not be displaying them on a user's timeline or activity log going forward.

[This ticket](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149874215169614) specifically about the news.reads action was marked as a duplicate of the ticket mentioned above.

---

I'm currently having the same issue. Posted actions to news.reads return successful Open Graph objects but any notification in the Activity Log is gone... in fact, all past news.reads for my application are gone as well.

I did some experimenting with http://www.huffingtonpost.com/&fref=ts">Huffington Post's social reader app to find that their application's read action was also not generating any notifications in my Facebook Activity Log, despite the fact that the Open Graph actions were valid.

Facebook's documentation does hint that they are moving away from emphasizing app actions as a result of consuming content (which can be seen through their relatively new ["Explicit Sharing" option](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/) on all Open Graph actions):

> There are some activities that happen naturally in the flow of your app that you may want to publish but which the user may not want to highlight explicitly on their timeline. These could be actions like listening to a song or reading an article.

Unfortunately though, this is just conjecture as Facebook has made no mention of the change in their [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/).